# Enable and Configure proxy using CMD

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

seeking your support to create a bat (CMD) file that can be used by standard user and administrators that can configure the proxy settings and the port number to be as shown below

proxy : 10.10.10.10 port number : 1111 and 
check mark bypass proxy settings and 
add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to the exceptions

thank you in advance

Comment: You want to "create a bat"? Aren't hose usually breeding in dark caves and reproduce by themselves?

Comment: What have you done so far? Noone here will write the program for you.

Comment: hi Guys,
i'm new here and i'm not sure how everything goes in here i was seeking the support of the professionals over here

@arkascha i prefer using command prompt or powershell that's all i know

Comment: @BDL i don't anyone to write the program for me, i just need a start or a small hint and what i have done so far is i have been Googling for a very long time and all i found is changing registry values and i don't need to go through all that and tried many other things and did not give me the expected results

Comment: Guys 
i more thing, in my opinion if my question is bothering your selves, just please ignore it and leave it to someone who can really help.

thanks

Comment: It is not bothering us at all. It is fine to ask a question here. Please forgive that I made a small joke meant to make you smile. Won't happen again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, one can modify the network settings via commandline by using the `netsh` command.

For example, changing the proxy works as follows:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy
```

or in your scenario:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 10.10.10.10:1111
```

Have a look at the detailed documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_5), and at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/489527/how-can-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-all-apps-system-ie-etc) superuser thread

Comment: Thank you So much
i do appreciate your efforts
one last thing if you don't mind 
what do you recommend to add exceptions inside the advanced tab

Comment: i can't change anything inside the exceptions bar i need to add addresses such as (10.* 20.*)